# Days in month validation

Tags: java, validation

Right not I'm trying to use `switch()` to validate the user input.
The scenario here is I am validating data corresponding to the calendar year.

I'm trying to validate that if you enter a month that contains 30 days (April, June, September, November), but enter a day value of 31, that it returns an error message.

I'm not going to lie. This is for an assignment, and I am in no way wanting ANYONE to just give me the answer, but if you can maybe explain what I am doing wrong.

Any help is great help. Here's the syntax for the two `switch()`es I have tried.

```
switch(monthInput)
```

First attempt:

```
case 1: 
 if((monthInput = 4 )&& (dayInput > 30))
 {
  System.out.printf("%n%d%s", dayInput, ERROR_MESSAGE[3]);
 }
 else if((monthInput = 6)&& (dayInput > 30))
 {
 System.out.printf("%n%d%s", dayInput, ERROR_MESSAGE[3]);
 }
 else if((monthInpt = 9)&& (dayInput > 30))
 {
 System.out.printf("%n%d%s", dayInput, ERROR_MESSAGE[3]);
 {
 else if((monthInput = 11) && (dayInput > 30))
 {
 System.out.printf("%n%d%s", dayInput, ERROR_MESSAGE[3]);
 }
```

Second Attempt:

```
switch(monthInput)
{
case 1:
   if((monthInput = 4 | monthInput = 6 | monthInput = 9 | monthInput = 11) && (dayInput < 30))
      {
      System.out.print("The day you entered is invalid for the month you specified
      }
                }
```

Comment: What issue are you having right now? One thing I see in the "Second attempt" is you have "|" for or instead of "||". Also, you have a single equals instead of two equals (= is assigning, == is comparing). Also, you're using a switch of monthInput, then in case 1, have a switch, where you check against 4, 6, 9, and 11. Since you have a case of monthInput is equal to 1, the if block will never pass.

Comment: `monthInput = x` is assignment and not condition. You need double `==`. You are using `switch..case` and `if..else` for same evaluation, thats redundant.

Comment: Also misspelt as "monthInpt", so ensure you test each and every monthvalue

Answer (score 1):

You can continue to use switch statements if you like. If you are switching on month then it would look something like:

```
switch(monthInput) {
    case 2: // feb
        if (dayInput > (leapYear ? 29 : 28))
            ...
        break;
    case 4: // apr
    case 6: // jun
    case 9: // sep
    case 11: // nov
        if (dayInput > 30)
            ...
        break;
    case 1: // jan
    case 3: // mar
    case 5: // may
    case 7: // jul
    case 8: // aug
    case 10: // oct
    case 12: // dec
        if (dayInput > 31)
            ...
        break;
    default:
        // error
}
```

If you have already learnt about arrays you might try having an array containing the number of days in each month and then comparing to the appropriate value using the month as index. Alternatively, you could use an `enum` of the months which would look something like:

```
public enum Month {
    JAN(31), FEB(28), MAR(31), APR(30), ....;

    private final int days;
    Month(int days) {
        this.days = days;
    }

    public int getDays(boolean leapYear) {
        if (this == FEB && leapYear)
            return days + 1;
        else
            return days;
    }
}
```

Getting the days in a particular month would be `Month.values()[monthInput].getDays(leapYear)`

Comment: This looks good, although don't forget leap years and to check if `monthInput` is above 12 or below 1.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `=` is used for assigning a value and `==` is used for testing equality.
Also OR uses `||` not `|`

so try

```
if((monthInput == 4 || monthInput == 6 || monthInput == 9 ||  
                            monthInput == 11) && (dayInput < 30))
{
  System.out.print("The day you entered is invalid for the month you specified");
}
```

Comment: "OR uses `||` not `|`" technically, "or" _can_ be `|`—the difference is short-circuiting.

Comment: @StephenLeppik `|` is a bitwise inclusive OR not a logical OR

Comment: `|` can still be used for booleans, though.

Answer (score 0):

The pathway a switch takes is determined by the controlling statement (in this case, `monthInput`). When you write `case 1` you're telling the switch what statements to execute when the value of `monthInput` is 1 (in other words, if the statements for `case 1` are being executed then we already know that `monthInput = 1`). So in this case, I'm not sure a switch is your best option as far as validation goes because it doesn't make sense to try to validate `monthInput` if you already know the value.

Also, as previously pointed out to check equivalence you use `==` not `=`, and `||` for the or operator.

Comment: Still new to this... as i'm still in my 3 month of school....   so thank you all for you patience with my typo, and rookie syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the obvious syntax error (`==`, `||`), the more important problem is you don't understand what `switch` is.

Read your book again for the section of switch, when you see

```
switch (A) {
case X:
   XXX;
case Y:
   YYY;
}
```

It should read: I am going to switch the logic based on value of `A`. `case X:` means, if `A` equals `X`, logic underneath will be executed.

In your case, you do something similar to:

```
switch(month) {
case 1:
    if (month == 4 || month ==6) {
        ...
    }
...
}
```

the line `case 1:` means, if `month` is `1`, but underneath it, you check if month equals to 4 or 6, which will never happen and not making any sense.

Please understand the tool before you try to use it.  Using it by blind guessing is not going to work.